# How to send multiple input entries into Flask in order to make web calculator?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am creating a web-based investment return calculator using Flask.

The user enters how many trades they have on record, and then I dynamically generate forms via javascript for them to enter the % gain on each.

I also have a field where they enter their starting capital. This is just one number, say $500.

Then in Flask I want to iterate over all the fields that have been created...

And multiply each percentage gain by the starting capital amount.

Then I need it to output.

Here's my HTML/JS code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayFields(){
 var c = document.getElementById("playNum").value;

 var d = document.getElementById("mydiv");

 while (d.hasChildNodes()){
    d.removeChild(d.lastChild);
 }

 for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="text";
    input.name="gain" + i;
    d.appendChild(input);
    d.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}

}
</script>

What's your starting value?
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" id="startValue"/>
</form>

How many plays do you wish to calculate?
<form id="form2" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="playNum"/>
        <input type="button" name="button1" value="Submit" 
         onClick="displayFields();"/>
        <div id="mydiv">
        <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate"

</form>


</body>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to send each value into Flask, store it, and then create a function that does the math.

After that, I would like to output back into the web browser.

Any hints? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Since mydiv is in your form, why can you not access it in Flask?

Comment: I can. I'm just unsure how to iterate over each instance of the input fields, since they are dynamically generated by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think Flask just returns a dictionary, right? Can you loop in that dictionary?

```
for item, val in request.form.items():
    #do something with item`
```

Otherwise, if there are other items in that form and you only want to loop over the dynamically generated stuff, you could do:

```
i = True
c = 0
while i != None:
    i = request.form.get("gain" + str(c))
    #Do something with i`
    c += 1
```